# Does WildFly use jakarta.* api or are the javax.* apis still compatible

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jakarta-migration

I've updated my project from Java 11 to 17 and accordingly I had to update my WildFly version from 15 to 25 because the WAR of Java 17 is not compatible with WildFly 15. Question is, do I have to migrate from `javax` to `jakarta` because the WildFly now supports the Jakarta EE 8 after WildFly 17 release? So is it really compulsory to move to `jakarta` from `javax` or there is a workaround for this?

Comment: it should be the jakarta-ee version according to the docs: https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/10/05/WildFly25-Final-Released/ 

```The standard WildFly 25.0.0 distribution is a Jakarta EE 8 compatible implementation, compatible with both the Full Platform and the Web Profile. Evidence supporting our certification is available for the Full Platform and for the Web Profile.```

Comment: @meaningqo Really sorry but I didnt get this properly. Like do I have to migrate to jakarta for wildfly 25 or I can still use the javax packages and the same in the .xml file.

Answer (score 10):

Jakarta EE 8 (Sep 2019) stil uses the `javax.*` package. It's essentially exactly the same as Java EE 8 (Aug 2017), it was only the brand name that has changed. Jakarta EE 9 (Nov 2020) was the first to use the `jakarta.*` package. It's essentially still exactly the same as Java EE 8, but now with the brand name *and* package name changed. Jakarta EE 10 (Sep 2022) continues using the `jakarta.*` package, but is essentially the first version after Java EE 8 with actual changes and new things in the API.

Note that WildFly [comes](https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/) as "WildFly" and "WildFly Preview". As per the [docs](https://docs.wildfly.org/):

WildFly versions 17 - 26 are Jakarta EE 8.
WildFly Preview versions 22 - 26 are Jakarta EE 9.
WildFly *and* WildFly Preview versions 27 -30 are Jakarta EE 10.

In your specific case, you apparently have a Jakarta EE 8 application and a WildFly 25 server. So as long as you have picked "WildFly 25" and thus not "WildFly Preview 25", then you're fine. A quick way to verify is to blindly deploy your `javax.*` targeted WAR to the server and check if it doesn't throw any `NoClassDefFoundError` errors on `javax.*` classes during runtime.

By the way, the latest WildFly version supporting Jakarta EE 8 is 26, and this is the one currently still actively maintained (at the time of writing, 26.1.3 was released only 9 days ago, and 25.x is not anymore maintained more than a year), so I strongly recommend to upgrade a step further from WildFly 25 to WildFly 26.

That said, you should really migrate to `jakarta.*` as next step because `javax.*` is clearly a dead end. Also, noted should be that this all has got completely nothing to do with Java SE 17 version. Moreover, Jakarta EE 10 is still Java SE 11 compatible.

#### See also:

- [How to use Java EE and Jakarta EE dependencies together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862464/how-to-use-java-ee-and-jakarta-ee-dependencies-together)
- [How to handle javax.net and javax.sql imports while upgrading to SpringBoot 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364511/how-to-handle-javax-net-and-javax-sql-imports-while-upgrading-to-springboot-3/76364735#76364735)