# Can't migrate javax.security.auth.x500 to Jakarta EE

Tags: java, jakarta-migration

We are moving away from javax to Jakarta EE, and we migrated almost all of our packages except one:

```
javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal
```

There is a `jakarta.security.auth` package already, but the content is slightly different. No matter how much I searched, I couldn't find the equivalent of this package in Jakarta. Am I missing something here?

I am no security expert, so I don't have much preliminary knowledge about the subject.

Comment: That class isn't part of Jakarta EE. It's part of [Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html). Why exactly did you think you need to migrate it? Did it give compilation errors? Related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76364735. The `jakarta.security` package is basically for the Jakarta EE equivalent of "Spring Security", as seen here: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/security/3.0/jakarta-security-spec-3.0

Comment: @BalusC No compilation errors. During the migration, I noticed `javax.annotation.PreDestroy` also had a Jakarta equivalent even though it is part of Java SE. So I wanted to know if it's the case for X500 as well and eliminate all javax.* packages if possible.

Comment: `@PreDestroy` is **not** part of Java SE. [Look over there in Java SE documentation, it's nowhere](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/allpackages-index.html). So if `javax.annotation.PreDestroy` compiles fine then you have a dependency problem.

Comment: @BalusC Yes it compiled fine. Thanks for pointing out. I am also ok to make this question duplicate with your suggestion.