Is there a Jakarta namespace version of Apache Commons IO?
Our system uses the latest version of Apache Commons IO (2.17.0). But this version uses the javax namespace instead of Jakarta. Our system uses Spring Boot 3 and therefore requires the Jakarta namespace. So I wonder, is there a Jakarta namespace version of Apache Commons IO? If not, how can we proceed? It would take a long time to replace Apache Commons IO with another library.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76590516/133203

Specifically which part of Apache Commons IO would be affected? As far as I'm aware, it is purely Java SE, so doesn't have Java EE 8 or older dependencies.

It seems like the javax version still can be used : https://github.com/jakartaee/platform/blob/main/namespace/unaffected-packages.adoc

The only things affected are dependencies that were part of Java EE 8 or older, and are now in Jakarta EE 9 with a renamed package namespace. There are also libraries and parts of Java SE itself that still use the javax.* namespace. Just because something has the javax.* namespace does not mean it needs to be replaced with a jakarta.* counterpart (because, again, only things in Java EE, now Jakarta EE, are affected).

Why do you think you need to do anything? Are you facing a specific problem?

This is what actually happened to you and therefore the duplicate you was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76364511

Only javax usage inside Jakarta EE is affected by modification restrictions. Several javax package exist outside Jakarta EE and are therefore in no way affected. Apache Commons IO uses javax.imageio, which is one of them.

Over the decades, many of the parts of Java were given javax.* package names by Sun Microsystems, then later Oracle Corp (having acquired Sun).
Some of those parts, but not all, were the group of technologies called Java EE (Enterprise Edition). In recent years, those Java EE parts were donated by Oracle to the Eclipse Foundation where they were renamed Jakarta EE. As part of the transition, the package names changed from javax.* to jakarta.*.
Many parts of Java using javax.* package names were not part of Java EE, and were not donated. These continue to be bundled in JDK/JRE products using the same javax.* packages. These have not changed names, so you need not do anything, no changes needed in your codebase.
Third-party libraries such as those found in the Apache projects have code that refers to the javax.* parts of Java. If those referenced interfaces and classes remain in Java, not donated, then their package names remain intact. If those referenced interfaces and classes were donated, then (a) you must obtain a new version of that library that has been updated to Jakarta EE, and (b) you’ll need to change the relevant package names in your codebase.
If you use the technologies in any but the first release of Jakarta EE, then you must use the jakarta.* package naming for Jakarta EE related interfaces and classes. Jakarta EE versions 9, 10, and 11 use the new package naming, while Jakarta EE 8 used the old package naming.
