# Where are the adapters for javax to jakarta migration?

Tags: jakarta-migration

We have an app with several JavaEE servlets (ie they use the javax.servlet package naming) but have been forced into upgrading our container to the newer Jakarta EE classes (ie jakarta.servlet) due to a number of technical issues too long to list.

We are not at liberty to rewrite the javax.servlets because the servlet classes come from another library to which we don't have access.

Before I start to implement the necessary adapters from javax to jakarta, has anyone already implemented them? I've searched but surprisingly haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but we're seeing the same problem. Have you constructed a strategy?

Comment: After spending several days trying to build something but running into ever deeper problems we ended up finding wholesale replacements for those libraries and rewrote everything around it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Java EE and Jakarta EE dependencies together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862464/how-to-use-java-ee-and-jakarta-ee-dependencies-together)