# Project upgrade with RichFaces getting compilation error for org.richfaces.event.DataScrollerEvent

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jakarta-migration

We have upgraded JSF project. We converted all `javax.faces.*` packages with `jakarta.faces.*` but project in not getting compiled.

For `org.richfaces.event.DataScrollerEvent` getting compilation error.

`org.richfaces.event.DataScrollerEvent` is extended from `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent` but now we have to use `jakarta.faces.event.ActionEvent`.

How is it possible?

code which is not compiling.

```
DataScrollerEvent dataScrollerEvent = actionEvent //jakarta.faces.event.ActionEvent.
```

Have to use `jakarta.faces.event.ActionEvent` instead of `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent`  with  `org.richfaces.event.DataScrollerEvent`

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to upgrade RichFaces too.

But that's going to be a bit difficult. [RichFaces is EOL since June 2016](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-55384), so it is not anymore actively maintained by the original developers. There is currently only one fork at Github which is still active, [the RichFaces fork of Alberto Fernández](https://github.com/albfernandez/richfaces), but it has currently no jakartified version. You might want to try to open an issue over there with a request to create a jakartified version. Or you could just fork it further yourself and jakartify it yourself. Alternatively, you could use the [Eclipse Transformer](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer) to jakartify a JAR library, see also [How to use Java EE and Jakarta EE dependencies together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70862464/how-to-use-java-ee-and-jakarta-ee-dependencies-together)

But, in long term perspective, you *really* need to bite the bullet and replace RichFaces by a currently still actively maintained JSF component library such as [PrimeFaces](https://primefaces.org). It has a fine [`<p:dataTable>` component with extensive paginatior](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml) (same as "data scroller" as they call at RichFaces).

Comment: I tried with eclipse transformer but it's generated same output jar which is not conversion of jakarta. java -jar org.eclipse.transformer.cli-0.5.0-distribution.jar javaxJar.jar

Comment: package com.org.event;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.richfaces.event.DataScrollerEvent;
public class JakartaDemo {
 public void actionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
  DataScrollerEvent dataScrollerEvent = (DataScrollerEvent)actionEvent;
  int pageId = dataScrollerEvent.getPage();
 }
}

Comment: created source jar with importing richfaces and javax package. Could you please help what am I missing here?

Comment: You need to transform the RichFaces JAR file nor your own JAR file. Then in your own JAR file just use jakarta imports all over place as usual.